# the difference between fast/quick/rapid

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

> She is a karate coach. She is not very powerful, but she is very quick/fast/rapid.

Can I use all three words *quick, fast* or *rapid* in the sentence?

Could you tell me the different meanings between them, if they are fine here?

Answer (score 11):

Macmillan Dictionary defines *[quick](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/quick)* ("able to move fast or do something fast") and *[fast](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/fast#fast_4)* ("able to move quickly") in terms of each other, so there's not much to choose between them.

Either is a desirable trait in a striking art like karate; force equals mass times *acceleration*, after all.

On the other hand, Macmillan defines *[rapid](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/rapid)* as "*happening*, *moving*, or *acting* quickly," rather than *being* quick or fast.

Answer (score 7):

*[Fast](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fast#Adjective)* and *[quick](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quick#Adjective)* can be used here, and which one you use depends on the facts of the case.  An article called [The difference between FAST and QUICK in martial arts](http://fightmash.com/?p=248) by ‘Anakonxx’ explains the difference in this context:

> Being quick means delivering a technique with explosive speed. Fast is speed without the explosiveness. The former should be the goal of any combat sport devotee.

Some comments in the final paragraph of that article suggest that strength is an important element of quickness:

> Lastly, let’s talk about strength in relation to being fast and quick. Once the student learns the mechanics of the technique, the timing is beautiful, your perception speed is marvelous, and your delivery is impeccable. You are only fast, but you are not quick yet. You need to add strength to the strike. ...

If you agree with the martial-arts article’s definitions of *fast* and *quick* and the comments about strength, then saying “She is not very powerful” might preclude calling her quick; she might merely be fast.

Some previous answers note that *rapid* isn't suitable.  This is a matter of usage (see ngrams for [she is...](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=she+is+fast%2Cshe+is+quick%2Cshe+is+rapid&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) and [he is...](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+is+fast%2Che+is+quick%2Che+is+rapid&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3)) rather than of grammar.  I think *rapid* is commonly used to characterize actions or processes, but not people.

Comment: I've heard something similar watching football, with commentators differentiating between "speed" or being "fast," which means what you'd think, and "quickness," which has to do with being able to change directions or take off on a dime -- maybe a bit like "acceleration."

Answer (score 5):

*Quick* is best, although *fast* is ok.

But at least for me, you can’t use *rapid* here; it doesn’t seem to apply directly to people like that.

Comment: Yes, quick relates to acceleration, while fast relates to speed. One could have a very fast top speed but could take a long time to build up to that speed, while another could be very quick to react but their top speed might not be that fast.

Comment: Question asks for "Could you tell me the different meanings between them", would be better to expand on that.

Comment: @deworde: O.P. also asks for "if they are fine here," and "can I use all three," so tchrist has answered much of the question. (Not every answerer need answer every part of a three-part question.)

Comment: @Xavier off-topic comments will be deleted on sight. There are better uses to put your time to.

Comment: Quick relates to performance, time elapsed, not just acceleration or movement speed. You can be fast, but overshoot your moves, waste time on hesitation between them, or require to take two or three tries to get it done. Or you can be just very efficient, with moderate speed but always striking true - quick to finish the task.

Comment: @tchrist:Could you please explain why quick is best, although fast is ok? Thanks.

Comment: @atsea Not really, it’s just the feel.  *Quick* seems a bit unexpected, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand:

1. **Quick**: refers to **time**, it describes something that is done in a short period of time or without any delay;
2. **Fast**: refers to **speed**, it describes something moving at high speeds;
3. **Rapid**: refers to **time**, but at which rate something changes, that is, either increases or decreases;

That being said:

> She is a karate coach. She is not very strong, but she is very
> **quick**.

Means that she makes decisions in no time and her movements take short periods of time to be completed.

> She is a karate coach. She is not very strong, but she is very
> **fast**.

Means that she can run at high speeds.

> She is a karate coach. She is not very strong, but she is very
> **rapid**.

Is incomplete, and would not get to the original meaning you wanted. It to be changed to something like:

> She is a karate coach. She is not very strong, but her students had
> **rapid** progress.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give reference, but just let you know that to my American ear, "quick" or "fast" are both good, but "rapid" seems unnatural in that context.

Answer (score 1):

"Fast" is the best choice.

Quick and fast are almost identical in meaning, but quick also has the connotation in a sentence such as that of being quick on the uptake, quick to learn, etc., while fast does not and implies quick in movement only.  Unless, of course, you want to express those other implications as well.

Rapid simply does not fit the context.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you should be able to differentiate between the three now.
But ever tried to use something else, all these words are relative, in other words, fast means do something like moving quickly but relative to something else.

I would recommend you taking your reader imagination a bit further and you relate for the reader.

She is a karate coach. She is not very powerful, but she is as fast as an eagle attacking a prey.

Answer (score 1):

I am a Russian and English is not my mother tongue. Yet I have an idea. I think that 'quick' implies some motivation or stimulus. If you eat something quickly you do it because you want to do something else after eating. 'Rapid' implies 'no obstacles'. In this canteen you can eat rapidly because there will be no waiting time, there will be no obstacles to your eating. 'Swift" means 'in a great hurry'. If he eats swiftly his food, it means that he swallows his food with little chewing. And 'fast' means just 'with high-speed'. You must slow down your fast eating pace.

Answer (score 1):

As an enthusiast of bikes, quickness is measured in terms of acceleration while fastness is considered in terms of speed.

Comment: Could you provide, for example, links to Internet references that support your definitions?  Thanks! and welcome to English.SE!

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer "Quick" as defined in Dictionary.com

1.
done, proceeding, or occurring with promptness or rapidity, as an action, process, etc.; prompt; immediate: a quick response.  

2.
that is over or completed within a short interval of time: a quick shower.  
3.
moving, or able to move, with speed: a quick fox; a quick train.  
4.
swift or rapid, as motion: a quick flick of the wrist.  

5.
easily provoked or excited; hasty: a quick temper.

Comment: That’s a horrible dictionary.  The OED has over 30 major senses for *quick*, plus many more subsenses beyond even those.

Comment: Its a simple dictionary for those who need it though.

Comment: FWIW, [Onelook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=quick&ls=a) will get you links to several online dictionaries, some that are quick and simple, and others that are more in-depth.