# "Fast" vs "Quickly" vs "Speedy" vs "Rapidly"

Tags: differences, word-usage, connotation

A [similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78110/the-difference-between-fast-quick-rapid) has been asked.

However, is it possible to give (general) differences in usage of  *fast*, *quickly*, *speedy*  and *rapidly*?

And with respect to [the top answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78114/61752): Are *quick* and *fast* absolutely interchangeable?

Comment: No two English words are absolutely interchangeable.

Comment: Pitchers throw *fast balls*, not *quick balls*. You dance the *quickstep*, not the *faststep*.

Comment: Nobody ever says 'The fast and the dead'

Comment: There is also the matter of the adverbial '-ly' suffix, which American English tends to avoid. 'I ran quick' vs 'I ran quickly'.

Comment: Besides the association with 'life' or 'living', *quick* generally refers to acceleration.  Consider two hypothetical cars: a car that could go from 0-60mph in one second but had a top speed of only 65mph would be **quick** but not **fast**; a car whose top speed was 500mph but took ages to accelerate to that speed would be **fast** but not **quick**.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think it is strictly possible to give guidelines to usage that are anything other than pedantic.  I do, however, think that etymology provides some helpful clues to the more natural contexts of usage.

Quick is related to life and living things such that "quick as a rabbit" seems natural.

Fast has its relationship to strength and force that makes "fast cars" and "run a fast race" seem  like a good fit.

Speed is related to success and goals giving "speed limit" and "speedy delivery" their purposeful ring.

Rapid has a hunger to it that makes it well suited to phrases like "consume at a rapid rate" or "rapidly overtaking."

Mixing these up produces some odd results: "Rapid rabbits" are comprehensible but more predatory that we are used to rabbits being.  "Quickness limits"  Nonsense.  "Quick delivery?"  Something else entirely.  A baby has been born.  Further evidence that "quick" wants to talk about life.

There are certainly no rules, just clues buried in the historical antecedents of the modern words. I would say try "quick" first for natural systems and living things and use "fast" as the go-to for machines, forces and acts of power. Rapid has a dark side. Speed is ambitious.

Comment: Speed: Old High German spuon to succeed 

Quick: Gothic qius alive 

Fast: Middle High German vaste firmly

Rapid: Latid rapere to seize

Comment: Concise explanation, vivid examples.

Comment: Quick delivery can be a pizza just as much as a baby.  And probably more often.

Comment: NGram disagrees. Writers in the modern era are more likely to use "quick delivery" for the birth of a child.  (quick delivery+baby),(quick delivery + pizza).  However adjusting for the relative frequency of the words pizza and baby: ((quick delivery+baby)/baby),((quick delivery + pizza)/pizza) does reveal that rarely when talking about a baby is quick delivery the key point. Pizza however has less going on and quick delivery of a pizza is one of its most salient features.

Comment: Would you say "the value decreases rapidly/quickly/other..."?